# string to Date Conversion Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, datetime-format

Very stupid thing but need to achieve in VB.net. I was trying to do this in VB.Net VS2008 .Net Framework 3.5

```
Dim str As String = "25/05/2014"
Dim dt As Date
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
Console.WriteLine(dt)
```

And I am getting output as

```
25-05-2014 00:00:00
```

Any idea?

Comment: Well it's parsing your date correctly as far as I can see... you're then just using the default `ToString` implementation to convert it back to a string. What did you expect and why?

Comment: I want to get exactly like dd/MM/yyyy format and no time as well. Format should be 'dd/MM/yyyy' not like 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'

Comment: Then you need to format it that way. A `DateTime` value has no concept of a format, any more than an integer which *happened* to be parsed from hex remembers that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the conversion, which is OK. When the date is written to the console it is formatted (i.e. converted to a string) with a default format that happens to include the time part.

Specify the desired format when printing:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt)
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Note: the `Date` structure (which is the same as the `DateTime` structure) stores the date and time in a format neutral way, i.e. you cannot format the `Date` structure. However, when you output it to the user, the date will have to be converted into human readable form, i.e., it will have to be converted to a string. Whenever you convert some binary data (numeric, date/time and so on) into a string, a format will determine how the result will look.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a hurry, this is a simple way to get the data you want:

```
    Dim sFormatted As String = dt.Day.ToString() & "/" & dt.Month.ToString() & "/" & dt.Year.ToString()
    MessageBox.Show(sFormatted)
```

Comment: The string concatenation operator in VB is `&`, not `+`.

Comment: You may want to avoid using legacy functions like MsgBox. Use Messagebox.Show() instead.

Comment: This works for me....but should not be any easy way to achieve this just by using format?

Comment: @user1841927 The other answer explains it.